Mutual information expansion not justifiable
I have recently read a mutual information term,
$I(X;Y,Z)=E_{p(X,Y,Z)}\big[\log\frac{ p(X|Y,Z)}{p(X)}\big]$.
While this expansion does not make sense to me. Is it correct? My understanding (using knowledge from here) is that LHS of the above mentioned expression finds the mutual information between $X$ and the joint distribution of $(Y,Z)$. So in that case the denominator in my opinion should be $p(X,Y)*p(Y,Z)$. Wheras I have no clue for how the numerator is obtained.
The conditional mutual information expression I read from here is as follows,
$I(X;Y|Z)=-E_{p(X,Y,Z)}\big[\log\frac{ p(X,Y|Z)}{p(X|Z)p(Y|Z)}\big]$. What can be the proper expansion of $I(X;Y,Z)$?

The expression you have is correct. However, unless you tell us why you think that the expression does not make sense, we can't help you with the intuition, or tell you how you're going wrong. So: why does the expansion not make sense to you? Did you try to prove the expansion? Did you find a counterexample? Please add your work to the question.

Thanks for the comment. I have re-drafted the question and tried to add more clarity. My fundamental doubt remains how to decide the numerator and denominator expression.

Two ways to see this: 1) think of $(Y,Z)$ as one random variable, $U$. Then $I(X;U) = \mathbb{E}_{p(X,U)}[ \log p(X,U)/p(X)p(U)],$ and $p(X,U)/p(U) = p(X|U)$ and you can re-expand $U$. 2) we know via the chain rule that $I(X;Y,Z) = I(X;Z) + I(X;Y|Z)$. You have a slight error in the expression for $I(X;Y|Z)$ (this is a typo in the source, the second line after (32) is correct), there shouldn't be a negative sign, but you can derive $I(X;Y,Z)$ from this and $I(X;Z)$. Of course, validity of this derivation would depends on how you defined conditional m.i. to begin with.

As for why there should be a $p(X,Y) p(X,Z)$ in the denominator: you don't really explain your reasoning, so I don't know how to correct this, beyond that this is not the case. More broadly, depending on the time you have, I'd suggest reading a good textbook, e.g. Cover and Thomas, rather than notes that have uncorrected typos.

It's really simple. Think of $(Y,Z)$ as a single multivariate variable $W=(Y,Z)$.
Then $$\begin{align}I(X;W) &= E \left[\log \frac{P(X,W)}{P(X)P(W)}\right]\\
&= E \left[\log \frac{P(X|W)}{P(X)}\right]\\
&= E \left[\log \frac{P(X|Y,Z)}{P(X)}\right]
\end{align}
$$
